# Format data from multiple lists in Visual Web Part formatted like Standard List

Tags: visual-studio, visual-web-part, c-sharp

I'm trying to roll data from multiple lists into one web part using Visual Studio, preferably a Visual Web Part. I want it to look like a normal SharePoint list view, with options to sort, filter, and group (and select an item with inline checkbox if possible). I've gotten close using SPGridView, but setting AllowFiltering and AllowSorting didn't make filtering/sorting appear. SPListView has the look I want, but I could only get it to bind to one list.

What class would be the best starting point, and should use a visual web part or basic web part?

Comment: If you are able to add some Angular, take a look at http://ngofficeuifabric.com/demos/uifTable/  It will be more (SharePoint) future proof

Comment: I've assumed Angular is client-side?

Comment: Yes, see [Angular.io](http://angular.io). With the new SharePoint Fx (aka SharePoint Future, aka Sp2016) the focus will be more and more on Front-End technologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPGridView can be customised to make it look similar to list view.

For filtering and sorting you need to code and handle OnSorting and OnFiltering events.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/pagination-sorting-and-filtering-in-spgridview/